# Why do I get a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' when setting the Text for a row cell?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Using a number of queries, as shown in the code below, I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' - Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values

on this line:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = count;
```

What could be the problem? I tried countless different things, but I can't get it working. I am a novice at this.

```
SqlConnection conn;
conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\ForumDB.mdf") + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand comm;
comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(ThreadId) FROM [Threads] WHERE [TopicId] = @TopicId", conn);
SqlCommand comm2;
comm2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(PostedDate) FROM [Threads] WHERE [TopicId] = @TopicId", conn);
SqlCommand comm3;
comm3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT PostedBy FROM Threads WHERE PostedDate=(SELECT MAX(PostedDate) FROM [Threads] WHERE [TopicId] = @TopicId", conn);

//FOR COMMAND1 CMD
comm.Parameters.Add("@TopicId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TopicId");
comm.Parameters["@TopicId"].Value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
string count = (comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = count;

//FOR COMMAND2 CMD1
comm2.Parameters.Add("@TopicId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TopicId");
comm2.Parameters["@TopicId"].Value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
string count1 = (comm2.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = count1;

//for command3 cmd2
comm3.Parameters.Add("@TopicId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TopicId");
comm3.Parameters["@TopicId"].Value = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
if (comm3.ExecuteScalar() != null)
{
    count2 = (comm3.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
}
conn.close();
```

Comment: Looks like your `e.Row` does not have four element. Did you debug your code and check it?

Comment: I can't seem to identify the problem, I tried changing some parameters but no luck

Comment: @rassii What is `e`? Where do you define it? How do you modify it? I am 99.(9)% sure that it has less than 4 cells in the `Row`.

Comment: What's the definition of 'e'?

Comment: no matter what value I change it to except 0 throws me the same error

Comment: @rassii, please have a look at my answer. Put a breakpoint on that line, and check the `e.Row.Cells.Count` property value. It will likely be 1.

Comment: Once I add the breakpoint how do I check the e.Row.Cells.Count value?

Comment: @rassii look at the "Autos" tab, it should list your `e` variable. Or move the mouse cursor over it and when the little window pops up, inspect its properties by expanding it by clicking the `>` symbol.

Comment: @Alex, in the Auto's count is 3

edit/ Even after changing the value to 3 it throws the same error

Comment: @rassii If `e` was null or `e.Rows` was null, you would have received a different exception: `NullReferenceException`. So I doubt that is is null. Try the following, when the breakpoint is hit, type `e.Row.Cells.Count` in the `Immediate Window` tab in Visual Studio.

Comment: It returned the value 3, yet that still throws me the same error

Comment: The value 3, means that you cannot do `Cells[3]`, because, you only have `Cells[0]`, `Cells[1]` and `Cells[2]`: **3** elements, not **4**

Comment: Thank you, those lines no longer throw an error. however when it reaches             if (comm3.ExecuteScalar() != null) it says  Incorrect syntax near '@TopicId'.

Comment: Which I can't seem to trace

Comment: @rassii you may want to ask a specific new question about that, as that no longer directly relates to this original question.

Comment: @alex i cant post for another two days

Comment: @rassii I updated my answer with a better way to get the results you need, using a single query. You will still need to make sure that the row cells exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this line:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = count;
```

Appears to be that this row does not have 4 cells. Check it by putting a breakpoint on that line, and looking at the value of `e.Row.Cells.Count`. It will be smaller than 4.

Also, you may want to change how you are performing your queries, because it seems you can get all the fields you need in a single query, instead of three separate ones:

```
const string query = 
    "SELECT PostedBy, PostedDate, COUNT(ThreadId) AS Count " +
    "FROM [Threads] WHERE [TopicId] = @TopicId " +
    "ORDER BY PostedDate DESC " +
    "LIMIT 1";

var fileToAttach = Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\ForumDB.mdf");
var connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + fileToAttach + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

var topicId = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
var postedBy = "";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopicId", topicId);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        { 
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                // NOTE: I am assuming you have these cells now!
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = reader["Count"].ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = reader["PostedDate"].ToString();
                postedBy = (string)reader["PostedBy"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```